# Python multi-thread crawler memory continues to grow

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler

I wrote a simple script in Python3. It enumerates all possible inputs of a POST request. The problem I have is the memory keeps growing after all the threads have been created, and finally, it will be killed by the system due to lack of memory. I checked the class myThread using Pympler. The result shows that the memory usage of all instances of myThread is not increasing rapidly. I have no idea what caused this memory leakage.

```
import requests
import threading
import time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, st, ed):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.st = st
        self.ed = ed

    def run(self):
        print("Starting "+self.name)
        get_range(self.st, self.ed)
        print("Exiting " + self.name)

def get_by_id(n):
    payload =  {"id":n}
    url = "http://www.example.com"  # This is for example
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                'Accept-Encoding':"gzip, deflate",
              }
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        return -2
    if r.status_code is not 200:
        return -2
    if "Cannot find" in r.text:
        return -1
    else:
        with open(os.path.join("./pages", n), 'w') as f:
            f.write(r.text)
        return 1

def get_range(a, b):
    for i in range(a, b):
        r = get_by_id(str(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for x in range(20):
        threads.append(myThread(x, "Thread-"+str(x), 800000000000+x*4000, 800000000000+(x+1)*4000))
        threads[-1].start()
        time.sleep(0.3)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print("Exiting Main")
```

Below is the code after removing all file operations which may cause memory problem.

```
import requests
import threading
import time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, st, ed):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.st = st
        self.ed = ed

    def run(self):
        print("Starting "+self.name)
        get_range(self.st, self.ed)
        print("Exiting " + self.name)

def get_by_id(n):
    payload =  {"id":n}
    url = "http://www.example.com"  # This is for example
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                'Accept-Encoding':"gzip, deflate",
              }
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        return -2
    if r.status_code is not 200:
        return -2
    if "Cannot find" in r.text:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1

def get_range(a, b):
    for i in range(a, b):
        r = get_by_id(str(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for x in range(20):
        threads.append(myThread(x, "Thread-"+str(x), 800000000000+x*4000, 800000000000+(x+1)*4000))
        threads[-1].start()
        time.sleep(0.3)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print("Exiting Main")
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the problem lies here

```
    else:
    with open(os.path.join("./pages", n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)
    return 1
```

You are opening a larger and larger file, and since opening the file writes it to ram, you are using a larger and larger amount of memory.

FYI: Memory leakage would not show up as allocated to a program, but instead as just unusable memory caused by a program failing to deallocate memory, but letting it go out of scope. Because of this, I know it is not a memory leak.

Update:
I decided to test out the program myself. Neither of them resulted in exponential memory growth, though they did increase while preparing to write but went down after write. The only advice I can give is to update to the most recent version of the request's module, and if that doesn't work, update python itself.

Comment: But the real situation is this "else" branch rarely happens, and as it is written  to a new file named by the value of "n" every time, I do not think that opening the file will take up more and more ram.

Comment: @brick: Well, can I get some more information. I.E Where do you store links that were found. For a web crawler to do it's job, it **has** to use larger and larger amounts of some kind of memory, whether it be ram or disk space.

Comment: I should not have called this script a crawler actually. What I did is enumerating all possible inputs to a certain url, thus I do not need any place to save the newly-found links like a normal crawler does. That's the strange thing.

Comment: Yes, it stores the response `r.text` when the response succeeds with status code 200 and there is no "Cannot find" in `r.text`. That is what the `else` branch does. This hit does not happen quite often. Also, every time when this happens, a new file named after `id` will be opened to record the `r.text` and then closed.

Comment: @brick: I figured out the problem. it is the `with open(os.path.join("./pages", n), 'w') as f:` you never close the file, leaving a handler and a copy of the file in ram. Since its a handler, you can't use a with-as statement;instead use `f=open(os.path.join("./pages", n), 'w')` then `f.write(r.text)` and then lastly `f.close()`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: I changed all `with` statement to `f=open()` and `f.close()`. However, this does not solve my problem. Even I remove all the file operations, the memory is still increasing.

Comment: @brick: OK, Can you post the new full code so I can take another look. This is really starting to bug me, and you to I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that open, in order to write to a file, must create a file hander in the operating system. You are creating a new file handler every time the open command is called. Instead, you should open the file handler once, and then pass it to get_by_id as an argument. Then there is only ever one file handler per thread.

Alternatively, you can use file.close() to release the operating system resources. This probably happens eventually due to garbage collection when the file moves out of scope, but relying on GC is very bad practice in this type of situation. In any event, creating unnecessary objects inside a loop is bad practice. So do something like:

```
import requests
import threading
import time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, threadID, name, st, ed):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.st = st
    self.ed = ed

def run(self):
    print("Starting "+self.name)
    get_range(self.st, self.ed)
    print("Exiting " + self.name)

def get_by_id(n, f):
payload =  {"id":n}
url = "http://www.example.com"  # This is for example
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            'Accept-Encoding':"gzip, deflate",
          }
try:
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
except Exception as e:
    return -2
if r.status_code is not 200:
    return -2
if "Cannot find" in r.text:
    return -1
else:
    f.write(r.text)
    return 1

def get_range(a, b):
with open(os.path.join("./pages", n), 'w') as f:
for i in range(a, b):
    r = get_by_id(str(i), f)
f.close();

if __name__ == "__main__":
threads = []
for x in range(20):
    threads.append(myThread(x, "Thread-"+str(x), 800000000000+x*4000, 800000000000+(x+1)*4000))
    threads[-1].start()
    time.sleep(0.3)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print("Exiting Main")
```

Comment: However, `with` can make sure that the file is closed, isn't it?

Comment: I didnt realise that with would call file.close(). But even so, that only instructs the operating system that the file handler can now be closed, it still might take some appreciable time. Much better to only open one file handler. Have you tried that? Did it offer any benefits?

Comment: I changed all `with` statement to `f=open()` and `f.close()`. However, this does not solve my problem. Even I remove all the file operations, the memory is still increasing.